# How to wait for new input from user in Telegram Bot?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm building a bot for Telegram to be able to users add to a spreadsheet "friends".
The idea is that when they start the bot they can simply write the name of the "friends" (e.g., @friend1 @friend2 @friend3), and they will be added to a new spreadsheet.

I'm writing in the Google Spreadsheet Script Editor.

Started to declare the variables, and set up the webhook.

```
var token = "token";
var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "spreadhsheetURL"
var ssId = "spreadsheeID";
var myID = "$$$$$$$"

function getMe() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getMe");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getUpdates() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getUpdates");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/setWebhook?url="+ webAppUrl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id, text) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text));
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hello " + JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

All is functioning but when I tell BOT to ask the user if the wants to add new friends the program doesn't wait for the user to write and gives the "Error" of the last else.

```
function doPost(e){
  try{
    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var text = contents.message.text;
    var id = contents.message.from.id;
    var name = contents.message.from.username;
        
    sendText(id, "Hi " + name + " do you want to add more friends? (Yes/No)");
    
    
    if(text == "Yes"){
      sendText(id, "Add new friends (e.g., @friend1 @friend2 @friend3)).");
      
      var sheetName = name;
      var newText = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
      
      //check if already exist the spreadshet
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) ? ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) : ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
      
      // check the number of words (friends)
      var str_len = newText.split(" ").length;      
     
      // Print friends per row
      for (i=0; i<str_len; i++){
        sheet.appendRow([new Date(), id, name, newText.split(" ")[i]]);
      }   
      
      sendText(id,"The user " + newText + " was added to your list " + sheetName + " with success.");
      
    }else{
      if(text == "No"){
        sendText(id, "Thank you.")
        
      }else{
        sendText(id, "Error.")
      }
    }
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
    
  }catch(e){
    sendText(myID, JSON.stringify(e,null,4));
  }
  
}
```

Want to know if anyone could help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try to use getUpdates. Refer to this link of the Telegram API documentation for more information: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I've tried it before and it can't get updates from the API because it's connected to it through the webhook.

Comment: Then, you need to use localstorage to save the state of the flow first. For example, before sending a message to telegram bot, save the "state" to the cache with some key. Then, in the webhook function, once received the reply from the user, try to get the key from the user's reply and load the state from the cache, then continue the flow. You can use Cache API to achieve it. See reference link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing one delivery for two processes at once, and each process needs to be responded to at its own time, so you have to separate each response from each process.

You can use the [**reply_markup**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) parameter with [**ForceReply**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) for data input needs, which is available in almost all send methods.

A little improvement, modified version to solve the problem:

```
function doPost(e){

    try {
    
        var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
        var text = contents.message.text;
        var id = contents.message.from.id;
        var name = contents.message.from.username;
    
        var answer = ["Yes","No"];

        if ( text === "/start" ) {

            sendText(id, "Hi " + name + " do you want to add more friends? (Yes/No)");

        } else if ( answer.includes( text ) ) {
  
            if ( text === "Yes" ) {
                
                //force user to input
                var dataForceReply = {
                  method: "post",
                  payload: {
                      method: "sendMessage",
                      chat_id: String( contents.message.chat.id ),
                      text: "Add new friends (e.g., @friend1 @friend2 @friend3))",
                      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                          "force_reply": true
                      })
                   }
               };
               UrlFetchApp.fetch( url + "/", dataForceReply );

            } else sendText(id, "Thank you.");

  
         //When the user provides feedback input 
         } else if ( (( contents || {} ).message || {}).reply_to_message ) {

            //Make sure the user's answer is for the same question                
            if ( contents.message.reply_to_message.chat.id == contents.message.chat.id ) {

                var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
                var sheetName = name;
                var newText = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
       
                //check if already exist the spreadshet
                var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) ? ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) : ss.insertSheet(sheetName);

                //check the number of words (friends)
                var str_len = newText.split(" ").length;      

                // Print friends per row
                for (i=0; i<str_len; i++){
                    sheet.appendRow([new Date(), id, name, newText.split(" ")[i]]);
                 }   
  
                 sendText(id,"The user " + newText + " was added to your list " + sheetName + " with success.");

             } else sendText(id, "Error.");

           }

       } catch(e) {
         sendText( myID, e );
       }

  }
```